# Meaning of Signed Long Integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following requirement:

Create the Linear List functions: CreateList, AddNode, DeleteNode, SearchNode and DeleteList, for a list holding signed long integers.

I am confused about 2 terminologies here 
does the meaning of signed long integers here means:

"any long integer which is positive or negative including 0" ?

am I missing something?

and 2nd

by "linear list" does it mean a singly or double linked list?

thank you

Comment: Tell your teacher if he / she asks stupid questions, then they get stupid prizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have the following requirement:
>
> Create the Linear List functions:

This wording is already strange for C++. In C++, several functions that work on the same data are usually grouped into a class.

> CreateList, AddNode, DeleteNode, SearchNode and DeleteList,

- A class has a name, in this case `List` or `LinkedList`.
- Since the functions are defined inside the class, their names don't need to contain the word `List` as that would be redundant.
- The function names should also not contain the word `Node` since that is an implementation detail about which the caller of these functions should not worry.
- The `CreateList` function should be the constructor of the class. Constructors don't have a name.
- The `DeleteList` function should be the destructor of the class. Destructors don't have a name.

> for a list holding signed long integers.

When designing a data type, it's easier at the beginning to work with a single concrete data type. Later that data type is usually replaced with a placeholder so that this list can be used with any type, making it a template class. For the purpose of this exercise, your teacher most probably means the single type `long int` (which is implicitly signed). If you want, you can also write `signed long int`, that's equivalent.

> by "linear list" does it mean a singly or double linked list?

We cannot tell you. That's something you have to ask your teacher.

In idiomatic C++, the basic structure of the type definition would look like this, I left out the implementation details:

```
class LongIntList {
public:
    LongIntList();   // This is the constructor
    ~LongIntList();   // The ~ marks this as the destructor
    void Add(long int element);
    void Delete(long int element);
    bool Search(long int element);
}
```

In the C++ standard library, the `Search` function looks a bit different (it returns an iterator instead of only a boolean value), but for a beginner, the boolean is good enough. Iterators will be taught later.

In summary, your current instructions will make you write code with a simple structure, which is good for learning. But be aware that the resulting code is not considered good C++ code. After introducing the necessary concepts, your teacher will hopefully let you transform the current code into good C++ later. If that doesn't happen in the next months, you can post your current code (which must work as intended) to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to let experienced C++ programmers tell you what it should really look like, and why.

Answer (score 0):

A 'signed' integer is an integer with a 'sign' bit indicating if it is a negative or positive value.

A 'long' integer that may be longer then an int depending on the architecture. On 32-bit a long is at-least 32-bit and the same size as an int, on a 64-bit system a long is 64-bit.

You do not need to specify 'signed' as it is the default, simply declaring a variable as a `long` will make it a signed long variable. On the other hand if you only wanted a positive going value, you would need to specify it as `unsigned long`.

For a signed integer, the maximum is 1/2 the maximum of an unsigned because it's split down the middle. For example, a 16-bit unsigned integer's range is 0 to 65535, but a signed 16-bit integer's range is -32768 to 32767.

A linear list is exactly that, a list that is in a linear order, it doesn't specify how you're to create it, however as the functions use the terminology "Node" I would assume that a Linked List would suit the paradigm more correctly. See `std::list` as this would likely suit what you're doing.

Comment: *A 'long' integer that may be longer then an int depending on the architecture. On 32-bit a long is 64-bit, on a 64-bit system a long is 64-bit.* no guarantees of any of this being correct. `long` is at least 32 bit and at least the same size size of `int`. Everything else is up to the implementation, and nothing prevents the implementor from making all integral data types 64 bit. Don't laugh. Cray used to do almost exactly this.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, this is exactly why I use `stdint.h` defines.

Comment: "nor can you" — I can.

Answer (score 0):

This is teaching terminology, here is the translation:

- **Linear List** - a list which is not circular (last node is not linked to the first node). Can be singly or double linked. If not specified, the teacher usually wants singly, but you should ask.
- **signed long integers** - the **long** type. Signed integers include negative numbers (int, long, etc.). Unsigned integers have only positive numbers (unsigned int, unsigned long, etc.).